# SwiftUI crash when setting preference "precondition failure: invalid input index: 2"

Tags: ios, crash, swiftui

Here is the code that used to work on `swift 5.1` and broke in `swift 5.2`. I am trying to set a preference key value to use button's frame elsewhere:

```
struct SubmenuButtonPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {

    typealias Value = [CGSize]

    static var defaultValue: Value = []
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
    }
}

struct SubmenuButtonPreferenceViewSetter: View {

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.clear)
                .preference(key: SubmenuButtonPreferenceKey.self,
                            value: [geometry.frame(in: .local).size]) // crash here
        }
    }
}

public struct FloatingButton: View {

    @State private var size = CGSize()

    public var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("a")
            }
            .background(SubmenuButtonPreferenceViewSetter())
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(SubmenuButtonPreferenceKey.self) { rect in
            if let r = rect.first {
                self.size = r
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {

    var body: some View {

        return NavigationView {
            VStack {
                FloatingButton()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It crashes with

> precondition failure: invalid input index: 2

If I write this into console it shows lots of errors, but then shows the correct frame

```
po geometry.frame(in: .local)  
=== AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 1144 ===  
=== AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 995 ===  
 ...more of these errors...   
=== AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 1007 ===  
▿ (0.0, 0.0, 160.0, 45.0)  
  ▿ origin : (0.0, 0.0)  
    - x : 0.0  
    - y : 0.0  
  ▿ size : (160.0, 45.0)  
    - width : 160.0  
    - height : 45.0
```

I tried playing around with where I put GeometryReader and call preference setter, but it always crashes unless I remove preference setter at all.

UPDATE: Updated the code, now it actually crashes, sorry about that. It stops crashing if I remove VStack or NavigationView, but I need them all exatly in those places.

UPDATE2: Filed a bug report https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/7689920

Comment: Provided components work fine (tested with Xcode 11.4), so the reason seems in different place.

Comment: @Asperi Sorry about that, I tried to make it minimal( It's actually a little library https://github.com/exyte/FloatingButton and it's its example that crashes on that line

Comment: @Asperi I narrowed it down, looks like I should be filing a bug report to Apple instead...